# The secret of KeyVault parameter '' cannot be retrieved. Http status code: 'Forbidden'. Error message: 'Access denied to first party service

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep, azure-service-principal

We have a Azure DevOps pipeline that we are using to deploy infrastructure to Azure using bicep files. In Azure, We have create a App Registration Service Principle and added it as a contributor to our Subscription, which we use as a Service Connection within Azure DevOps to allow us to deploy the required infrastructure.

In the pipeline we are creating a Key Vault and adding the Service Principle to the Access Policies. Further in the Bicep I am trying to get a secret to use as the password for another infrastructure resource, but I keep getting the following error:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "DeploymentFailed",
    "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"KeyVaultParameterReferenceSecretRetrieveFailed\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The secret of KeyVault parameter 'password' cannot be retrieved. Http status code: 'Forbidden'. Error message: 'Access denied to first party service.\\r\\nCaller: name=ARM;tid=f8cdef31...;appid=797f4846...;oid=f248a218...;iss=https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31.../\\r\\nVault: kv-kf-web-shared-fea-ne;location=northeurope'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-keyvault for usage details.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**main.bicep:**

```
// Module: Key Vault
module keyVaultModule '../../Bicep.Modules/keyVault.bicep' = {
  name: 'keyVaultDeployment'
  params: {
    application: '${application}-shared'
    environment: environment
    location: location
    tags: tags
  }
  scope: resourceGroup
}

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultModule.outputs.name
  scope: resourceGroup
}

// Module: SQL Server
module databaseServerModule '../../Bicep.Modules/databaseServer.bicep' = {
  name: 'databaseServerDeployment'
  params: {
    application: '${application}-shared'
    environment: environment
    location: location
    tags: tags
    keyVaultName: keyVaultModule.outputs.name
    password: keyVault.getSecret('password-databaseServer-sql-${application}-shared-${environment}-${shortlocation}')
  }
  scope: resourceGroup
}
```

**/keyVault.bicep**

```
// Resource - Function App
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        objectId: '{ AAD-GRP-Dev-DevOps Object Id }'
        permissions: {
          certificates: [
            'all'
          ]
          keys: [
            'all'
          ]
          secrets: [
            'all'
          ]
          storage: [
            'all'
          ]
        }
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      }
      {
        objectId: '{ Windows Azure Service Management API Object Id }'
        permissions: {
          certificates: [
            'all'
          ]
          keys: [
            'all'
          ]
          secrets: [
            'all'
          ]
          storage: [
            'all'
          ]
        }
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      }
      {
        objectId: '{ Windows Azure Service Management API Object Id }'
        permissions: {
          certificates: [
            'all'
          ]
          keys: [
            'all'
          ]
          secrets: [
            'all'
          ]
          storage: [
            'all'
          ]
        }
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      }
    ]
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
  }
}
```

**Key Vault Access Policies:**

[image]

Comment: Forbidden could also be a network issue. Do you have network restriction on the kV ?

Answer (score 6):

In the access configuration of Key Vault check the Azure Resource Manager for template deployment, and probably for VM if needed.
[Enable Template deployment for Key Vault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq6ak.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled onto the same problem and used the CLI:

```
az keyvault update  --name $keyvault --enabled-for-template-deployment true
```

I’m not sure if this was the original problem, but this is the solution for the deployment problem where the keyvault exists and the pipeline is trying to get adminpw or similar from there.